# Learning Polymer, getting ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm following https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html

I can't seem to get the code to run and I think it's because I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

devguide.js:

```
// register an element
MyElement = Polymer({

  is: 'my-element',

  created: function() {
    this.textContent = 'My element!';
  }

});

// create an instance with createElement:
var el1 = document.createElement('my-element');
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script src="./devguide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browsers with native html imports, like chrome, the polymer.html file is imported before your index.js script is run, so it has access to the Polymer variable.

I think you are using a browser without native html imports such as Firefox, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)

[Here](http://jsbin.com/coxifa/edit?html,js,output) is jsBin demo using your code that works in Chrome but not Firefox, (notice i'm also placing a `<my-element></my-element>` tag into the body, so you can see that it's working, otherwise it's the same as your example).

If this is the case, you can't include scripts registering elements in your head, you either have to put the script into a html file, such as

```html
<link rel="import" href="./devguide.html"></link>
```

devguide.html

```html
<script>
  MyElement = Polymer({

    is: 'my-element',

    created: function() {
      this.textContent = 'My element!';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Or you can include the script in your main html file, "index.html", but to do this, you have to wait to make sure the html imports are ready using [HTMLImports.whenReady](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#main-document-definitions)

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
      MyElement = Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        created: function() {
          this.textContent = 'My element!';
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/coxifa/edit?html,js,output)

When creating an instance of your element, instead you can either declare it in your index.html file wherever you want it like so:

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

or create it in javascript after waiting for the [WebComponentsReady](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready) event, but you have to actually place it into the dom if you use this method like so:

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {

    //- because you register it using MyElement = Polymer...
    var myElement = new MyElement();

    //- add it to the body, or wherever else you want, if you want to see it
    document.body.appendChild(myElement);
});
```

Comment: Should I put a quick summary at the top, explaining the problem is either using a browser without native html imports, or not actually putting his element into the dom?

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

How are you trying to view `index.html`? You may be hitting the issue described in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1535

For the HTML import to work you can't access it from a `file://` URL, you need to run a web server.

Comment: this could be the problem. Will try in the morning thanks.